# Creating Configuration Entities with entity reference in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8, entities

In drupal 8, is it possible to create complex configuration entities with reference entities? For example, to link multiple node in a configuration entities field? I haven't found documentation...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question but I will give you some clues to resolve your issue.

*Sorry if my answers doesn't fit you needs.*

Do you want only a configuration field linking multiple nodes ?

**or**

Do you want a custom Configuration Entity ?

---

### Configuration field

Use the field **entity_autocomplete** would help you.
Extra documentation here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2418529

Usage:

```
/**
* @file
* Contains A custom Class Form.
*/

// ... Namespaces & uses.

class AdminForm extends FormBase {

    // Class definitions

    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $extra = NULL) {
        $form['node_collection'] = array(
            '#type'          => 'entity_autocomplete',
            '#target_type'   => 'node',
            '#title'         => 'Nodes',
        );
    }
}
```

You should then save it in the State or the Config API.
Check this article for the difference between both (it will help you to choose the correct one): https://antistatique.net/en/we/blog/2016/06/14/drupal-8-differences-between-configuration-api-state-api

---

### Configuration entity

You should take a look at this documentation about Configuration Entity:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api/creating-a-configuration-entity-type-in-drupal-8

Then, you could look this answer, It will help you to create an `entity_reference` field for node or any entity you want.
[Retrieve a taxonomy term in the buildrow function of a drupal 8 custom entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45508304/retrieve-a-taxonomy-term-in-the-buildrow-function-of-a-drupal-8-custom-entity/45540488#45540488)

Hope it will help you !