# Retrieve a taxonomy term in the buildrow function of a drupal 8 custom entity

Tags: drupal-8

I have built a custom entity that works well. One of my fields is a taxonomy but I can not retrieve the name of the term in the `buildRow(EntityInterface $entity)` function which displays my records.

For a simple string field I do: `$row['foo'] = $entity->foo->value;`

How to do a taxonomy term that is an entity_reference: `$row['bar'] = $entity->BAR_TERM_NAME;`

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

To work as requested you need 3 things:

1. Implements an **entity_reference** field in your custom Entity.
2. Add a getter methode for you field.
3. Retrieve your field in your custom **ListBuilder** -> **buildRow()**.

Check the Drupal 8 documentation about [FieldTypes, FieldWidgets and FieldFormatters](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/fieldtypes-fieldwidgets-and-fieldformatters).

---

### Implements an **entity_reference** field

Your field **foo** in your Entity should be generated using the **entity_reference** field type.

```
public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  // Some code ...

  $fields['foo'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
    ->setLabel($this->t('Foo field'))
    ->setDescription($this->t('The Foo field.'))
    ->setSetting('target_type', 'taxonomy_term')
    ->setSetting('handler', 'default')
    ->setSetting('handler_settings', ['target_bundles' => ['vocabulary_id' => 'vocabulary_id']])
    ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
      'label'  => 'hidden',
      'type'   => 'vocabulary_id',
      'weight' => 0,
    ])
    ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
      'type'     => 'options_select',
      'weight'   => 40,
    ])
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);

  // Some code ...
}
```

You should then replace the 3 **vocabulary_id** by the vocabulary that you wanna links.

### Add a getter

In the same Class as your **baseFieldDefinitions**.

```
// Some code ...
public function getFoo() {
  return $this->get('foo')->value;
}
// Some code ...
```

### Retrieve the field

In your **ListBuilder** Class.

```
public function buildRow(EntityInterface $entity) {
  // Some code ...
  $row['foo']   = $entity->getFoo();

  // Some code ...
}
```

---

Hopes it will help you !

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

It will help people seeing the good answer on the page & this also helps contributor to keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.